# Tile pattern with two different tile thickness

Tags: tile

We are in the process of tiling our kitchen floor. We would like to do a pattern with two different tiles, some are large planks that are 1/2 thick while in the middle we will have some small tiles at 1/4 thick.

What's our best options to lay everything flat ? Using more Thinset under the 1/4 ones ? using a 5mm easymat ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5mm Easymat (or similar product) is the better solution. You don't want to build the thinset up too much.

Comment: Yes use a solid backing, thinset is not consistent enough.

Comment: Good morning, The EasyMat did the trick, very easy and quick to install. Thanks